# Doubt about what logical equivalence entails

Tags: logic

I'm having a hard time understanding the concept of logical equivalence in some specific cases. Suppose that C is equivalent to both A & B and A & B & D. Now suppose that we find out that D is false; does this entail that C is false? My answer would be yes, because of the conjunction's truth conditions (if D is false, then A & B & D is false, and given that the latter is equivalent to C, then C is also false). What do you think?

Comment: As you can see from some of the discussion below, there is some confusion as to what exactly your question is asking. Could you please clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First: it is impossible for $C$ to be *logically* equivalent to both $A \land B$ and $A \land B \land D$, for that would mean that $A \land B$ and $A \land B \land D$ are logically equivalent to each other, which they are not.

But, I suspect that you are not really talking about logical equivalence, but rather that you are given two biconditionals $C \leftrightarrow (A \land B)$ and $C \leftrightarrow (A \land B \land D)$ (which one could call *material equivalences*).

Well, with that as givens, and with $D$ being false, that means that $A \land B \land D$ is false as well, and hence $C$ is indeed false as well.

Comment: What if $A\land B\vdash\bot$?

Comment: @J.G. But $A \land B \not \vdash \bot$. The statement $A \land B$ does not *logically* imply a contradiction, because I find a possible truth-assignment that sets $A \land B$ to True (simply by setting both $A$ and $B$ to True) and that sets $\bot$ to False (of course, $\bot$ is *always* False).

Comment: It depends on what $A,\,B$ are. If you can assign them arbitrary truth-values, sure. But if $B$ is defined as $\neg A$...

Comment: @J.G I think what we disagree on is that I take $A$ and $B$ to be atomic statements, whereas you see them as statement variables.  So maybe that is what we should get clear on first.

Comment: More precisely, I don't know what to take/see them as.

Comment: The aquestion is ambiguous, but I took $A,B,C,D,E$ to be metavariables standing for first-order sentences. Under your reading it makes no sense to say that $C$ is logically equivalent to $A\land B$.

Comment: I also think that the convention to use $A, B, C$ as meta variables for formulas, and reserve $p, q, r, ...$ for propositional variables, is the more common one.

Comment: @lemontree Interesting ... I learned that just the other way around: capital letters as atomic statements, and $p$, $q$, $r$,.... as statement variables. But you could be right: maybe what I learned is the exception.

Comment: @bof Right .. which is why I figured the Op must have been talking about material equivalence ... but yes, maybe they are variables, that wouls solve the problem as well.  I wish the OP could provide a bit more guidance as to what the question really was/stated.

Comment: For what it' worth, I too am inclined to read $A$ and $B$ as atomic statements, but, lacking clarification, I'd go along with the OP's implicit suggestion that they are general statements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Logical equivalence just means sameness of truth value in all cases. When $C$ is true, $A \land B$ and $A \land B \land D$ must be true as well; when $C$ is false, $A \land B$ and $A \land B \land D$ must be false as well, and vice versa.

Note in this scenario, if we assume that $C$ is logically equivalent to both $A \land B$ and $A \land B \land D$, then $A \land B$ and $A \land B \land D$ must also be logically equivalent to each other.

This is because logical equivalence is an equivalence relation, meaning that it is

- reflexive: Every statement is logically equivalent to itself.
- symmetric: If one statement is logically equivalent to another, then the other is logically equivalent to the one.
- transitive: If A is logically equivalent to B, and B is logically equivalent to C, then A is logically equivalent to C.

All equivalence relations will partition the space into clusters of objects that stand in the given relation to each other. So if we take the scenario described by you as true, then $C, A \land B, A  \land B, A \land B \land D$, along with all other statemtents that are logically equivalent to them, such as $C \land C$, will form a cluster, in which all formulas are logically equivalent to each other. Then there will be another cluster with all tautologies (all tautologies are logically equivalent to each other), one with all the contradictions, one with all the formulas equivalent to $p \land q \to r$, ... The clusters will be independent of each other, but inside each cluster the truth values will coincide under all interpretations.

Imagine you have switches for the truth assignments of all the propositional variables, and each formula glows up green if it's true and red if it's false under that interpretation. Then under any combination of switch states, each cluster of logically equivalent formulas will uniformly glow up as green or red; though different clusters (groups of formulas not equivalent to each other) will in general show different colors. Two formulas being logically equivalent to each other means precisely that they belong to one cluster which uniformly comes out as true or false no matter the interpretation.

Maybe this observation helps you get a picture.

Note in particular that logical equivalence talks merely about truth conditions; it does not imply sameness of meaning or any form of causality. For instance, "If pigs can fly, then pigs can't fly" and "7 is prime and 7 is not prime" are logically equivalent to each other because they are both contradictions and therefore true or false in all the same cases, but they certainly do not have the same meaning, and neither is the reason for the other.